# Creation of server socket failed: port [port no.] cannot be opened

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I get the following error during parallel processing using `foreach` in R on a 64 CPU virtual machine (MS Azure, Windows Server 2019; code run on RStudio 2021.09.2 with R 4.1.2; note that RStudio and R are not fully up to date due to server restrictions).

`creation of server socket failed: port 11525 cannot be opened`

The port numbers may differ across errors.

This is how I call `foreach` (version 1.5.2)

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
no_clusters <- 64  # Equal to number of cores
cl <- makeCluster(no_clusters)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(task = task_list, .packages = ..., .combine = 'c', .inorder = F) %dopar% {
tryCatch(...)
}
```

I could not find this error documented online and I am not sure how to prevent it. It seems to occur randomly across repeated runs of `foreach` in parallel and is caught by `tryCatch`.

Comment: FWIW, that error happens in the `cl <- parallel::makeCluster(no_clusters)` call, which is used to set up the cluster of parallel workers. It's _not_ specific to **foreach**.

Comment: What is not clear from your question is whether this is an error you get each time, or sporadically.  (When I've seen that error, it has only been sporadically, and it only happens rarely - it works when retrying again.)

Comment: I missed you wrote "It seems to occur randomly across repeated runs ...".  Try with `cl <- parallelly::makeClusterPSOCK(no_clusters)` instead, because it tries multiple times if a parallel worker fails to launch (https://parallelly.futureverse.org/).

Comment: @HenrikB Thank you. I will try and let you know. Will take a moment to set this up. Indeed the problem seems to occur randomly across the elements in `task_list`; when it happens, the error is caught by `tryCatch`.